# How can I set default value in select without duplicate in list

Tags: html, freemarker

I have `select` control in my web page:

```
<select class="form-control" name="user">
    <#list sbUsers as sbUser>
        <option value="${sbUser.login}">${sbUser.login}</option>
    </#list>
</select>
```

But I need set current user like default value. Current user contains in this list and in other variable. I tried this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="user">
    <option value="${userName}" selected >${userName}</option>
    <#list sbUsers as sbUser>
        <option value="${sbUser.login}">${sbUser.login}</option>
    </#list>
</select>
```

But this realization not working. When I open my web page I have current user like default value but in list values this user contains too.

```
userCurrent(default)
  -user1
  -user2
  -user3
  -userCurrent
  -user4
```

but I need

```
userCurrent(default)
      -user1
      -user2
      -user3
      -user4
```

Comment: Either use inline if to set active class for specific item or exclude default item from the for loop

Comment: Just write a simple `if` that sets `selected` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select class="form-control" name="user">
                    <option value="">All</option>
                    <#list sbUsers as sbUser>
                        <#if sbUser.login == userName>
                            <option value="${sbUser.login}" selected>${sbUser.login}</option>
                        <#else>
                            <option value="${sbUser.login}">${sbUser.login}</option>
                        </#if>
                    </#list>
                </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this through JS

```
$('#mySelector').children('option[value="'Value'"]').hide();
```

Comment: JS instead of a simple `if`?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can use an [`if`](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_if.html)

```
<select>
    <option value="${userName}" selected>${userName}</option>
    <#list sbUsers as sbUser>
        <#if userName != sbUser.login>
            <option value="${sbUser.login}">${sbUser.login}</option>
        </#if>
    </#list>
</select>
```

Or if the default does not have to be first in the list:

```
<select>
    <#list sbUsers as sbUser>
        <option value="${sbUser.login}" <#if userName==sbUser.login>selected</#if>>${sbUser.login}</option>
    </#list>
</select>
```